# Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/ (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306)

Tags: php, mysql, iis, 3-tier

My company has a server where this student system is stored.this system is divided into few department.Specifically in 1 department,this error keeps on showing.i don't know what is the exact problem here.It was fine few days ago,since yesterday suddenly this issue started. This is the error

> Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/ (trying to connect via
>   tcp://localhost:3306) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\sms\cDatabase.php on line
>   29 Warning: mysql_connect(): Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. in
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\sms\cDatabase.php on line 29 Could not connect: 
>   Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
>   is normally permitted.

Can anyone please explain what is the exact problem here?i'm using php,mysql and iis for the localhost.thank you